# Is there a way to connect a bluetooth keyboard with Candy Box 2?

Tags: ios, candy-box-2

I can't get through a large portion of the game without using keyboard shortcuts and such in Candy Box 2. There is supposed to be a way to connect a keyboard to the app. I need this to get through the water level. I am on an iPad mini so the motion detector doesn't work for me in the app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not knowledgeable about iPads and bluetooth keyboards, but knowing that Candy Box 2 runs in a browser, it would seem reasonable to expect a keyboard to work in it if it can be used to type an URL into the address bar. If this is not possible, the whole setup might be flawed, so we'd need to debug the system to find the point of failure, which might be:

- The keyboard itself: Does it have any indicator that it is sending keystrokes?
- The bluetooth connection: Can you use the keyboard in other apps on the iPad?
- The OS or the browser: Can you use the keyboard in the browser at some other page?
- The Candy Box application: Can you load a completed save and try the computer?

Using this guide it should be possible to determine the point of failure, and so we could talk about fixing the problem.